# What are the categories for which average revenue is above the overall average

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I pass the greater than condition? I'm getting an error as invalid column name 'average'.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT P.prod_cat, AVG(total_amt) AS average 
FROM Transactions T JOIN 
     prod_cat_info P 
     ON T.prod_cat_code = P.prod_cat_code
WHERE average > AVG(total_amt)
GROUP BY prod_cat
```

Comment: Your query is clearly incorrect syntactically.   It also does not convey what you want to do.  Please provide sample data and desired results and a clear explanation.

Comment: You can't reference a column by it's alias in the `WHERE`. The only place you can do that is in the `ORDER BY`. Plus the fact that you have an aggregate in your `WHERE`. Even if that *were* correct, that would mean you're attempting to run a query where the value of `Average` is greater than `Average`, which is **impossible**. A value can *never* be greater than itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the title to your question, I think you want:

```
SELECT p.prod_cat, AVG(t.total_amt) AS average 
FROM (SELECT t.*, AVG(t.total_amt) OVER () as overall_average
      FROM Transactions T
     ) t JOIN
     prod_cat_info P 
     ON T.prod_cat_code = P.prod_cat_code
GROUP BY p.prod_cat, overall_average
HAVING AVG(t.total_amt) > overall_average;
```

Comment: I think you need some `JOIN` keywords in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to compare all of the rows to a single value you should make sure that you're only getting that single value once. The following code had decent performance in one of my larger local databases (table names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
WITH CTE_Overall_Avg AS (SELECT AVG(total_amt) AS overall_avg FROM Transactions)
SELECT
    TX.prod_cat,
    AVG(TX.total_amt) AS prod_cat_avg,
    MAX(OA.overall_avg) AS overall_avg
FROM
    Transactions TX
INNER JOIN CTE_Overall_Avg OA ON 1 = 1
GROUP BY
    TX.prod_cat
HAVING
    AVG(TX.total_amt) > OA.overall_avg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select prod_cat
From transactions as t 
inner join prod_cat_info as p 
on t.prod_subcat_code=p.prod_sub_cat_code and t.prod_cat_code = p.prod_cat_code
group by prod_cat
having avg(total_amt) > (select avg(total_amt) from transactions);
```

Answer (score 0):

What if Quantity and Amount columns are given separately? In that case we need to follow a different way to calculate the overall average and the Category-wise average. I have used CTE below which makes the code look very simple.

```
WITH CTE_Avg_Cat_Revenue AS(
   SELECT P.prod_cat, SUM(T.total_amt)/SUM(T.Qty) AS Cat_Avg
   FROM Transactions T
   JOIN prod_cat_info P
   ON T.prod_cat_code = P.prod_cat_code AND T.prod_subcat_code = P.prod_sub_cat_code
   GROUP BY P.prod_cat),
   
CTE_Overall_Avg AS(
   SELECT SUM(T.total_amt)/SUM(T.Qty) AS Overall_Average
   FROM Transactions T
   )
SELECT *
FROM CTE_Avg_Cat_Revenue, CTE_Overall_Avg
WHERE CTE_Avg_Cat_Revenue.Cat_Avg > CTE_Overall_Avg.Overall_Average;
```